# How to replace an entire table with pictures?

Tags: javascript, html

This is my table, of course with some text in it, and I want on a button click to hide it, and show some images. I also want to reverse the action on the same button click. How can I do that?

```html
<div id="aspect" style="display:yes">
    <table style="100%" id="Table">
        <tr>
            <th id="textul" > </th>
            <th id="textul4"> </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="testul2and3" style="vertical-align:top"> </td>
            <td style="vertical-align:top" id="textul6">
                <p> <iframe></iframe> </p>
            </td>                                         
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you try to toggle `hidden` attribute (where supported) or simply a `.hidden` class (defined as `.hidden { display: hidden }`?

Comment: Where are the images you talk about?

Comment: `style="display:yes"` isn't valid css.

Answer (score 1):

you can start with jQuery `.toggle()` method

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $("img").toggle();
});
```

this will work as you need

Have a look here: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: I don't know how that edit you made to the question got accepted, but ___don't ever___ change a question's code like that.

Comment: I'm sorry, what change shouldn't I did do? The inline style for `tr`?

Comment: Don't change a question's code. (Aside from indentation for readability).

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at this code sample. I have used jQuery 2.1.1

```js
$(function() {
  $('#toggler').click(function() {
    $('#Table').toggle();
    $('#imageblock').toggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="aspect">
<div style="display:none;" id="imageblock">
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" />
</div>
<table id="Table">
<tr>
    <th id="textul" > </th>
    <th id="textul4"> </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
  <td id="testul2and3" style="vertical-align:top"> </td>
    <td style="vertical-align:top" id="textul6">
            <p> <iframe></iframe> </p> </td>                                         
  </tr>
     </table>
</div>
<button id="toggler">Toggle Image/Table</button>
```